# A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color'

Tags: android, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

Trying to pass a default value for background color to the constructor but these are the error messages popping up.
I have tried using **Colors.red[200]! and Colors.red.shade200** but none of those worked out.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Category {
  final String id;
  final Color bgColor;
  final String title;

  Category(
    {required this.id, required this.title, this.bgColor = Colors.red[200]});
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this following answer :

```
class Category {
  Category({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    this.bgColor: const Color(0xFFEF9A9A),
  });
  final String id;
  final Color bgColor;
  final String title;
}
```

Comment: but why is this so?

Comment: A method that contains optional parameters does not force to pass arguments at calling time. It means we call method without passing the arguments. The optional parameter contains a default value in function definition. If we do not pass optional argument value at calling time, the default value is used.

Comment: that i understand what i am trying to ask is why can't we use Colors.red[200] directly. It doesn't return a current value or what?

Comment: The Colors.red[200] is not constatnt if you use simple Colors.red is accept so I used const value like const Color(0xFFEF9A9A)

Comment: just another question .. How do you determine the hex value for the colors in the pallet?

Comment: Refere https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html or When you write code in editor so that time **color : Colors.red** hover your mouse on red it gives the color box and then you found the hexadecimal value of any or perticular color.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this.

```
this.bgColor = const Color(0xFFEF9A9A)
```

The error is becuase, like the error says - *The default value of an optional parameter must be a constant.* And `Colors.red[200]` is not a constant but `const Color(0xFFEF9A9A)` is.