# Error A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color' in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a widget called CircleIcon, where I'm trying to add bgcolor by named argument.

```
class CircleIcon extends StatelessWidget {
    final IconData icon;
    final double iconSize;
    final Color bgColor;
    final VoidCallback onPressed;

    const CircleIcon({
        Key? key,
        required this.icon,
        this.iconSize = 25.0,
        this.bgColor = Colors.grey[200],
        required this.onPressed,
    }) : super(key: key);
```

As a default bg color , I'm trying to keep Colors.grey[200], but I'm getting error `A value of type 'Color?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Color'.`
If I change it to Colors.grey then it's working. What the type I will use for Colors.grey[200] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `const` before `CircleIcon` and using `Colors.blue[100]` means reading map and which is not  constant. It will get data on runtime.

You can explore it on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/ec20ea80ad98007bd022648168e7b3cc38b2e665/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart#L1825-L1841)

```dart
static const MaterialColor grey = MaterialColor(
    _greyPrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
       50: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      100: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      200: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
      //....
    },
  );
```

Therefore, you can not use `const` with color[value].

while `grey[200]` is `Color(0xFFEEEEEE),` you can use it.

```dart
this.bgColor = const Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, hope its help to you.

The `Colors.grey[200]` is **not constatnt** if you use simple `Colors.grey` is *accept* so I used const value like const `Color(0xFFEEEEEE)`

```
class CircleIcon extends StatelessWidget {  
  final IconData icon;
  final double iconSize;
  final Color  bgColor;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const CircleIcon({
    Key? key,
    required this.icon,
    this.iconSize = 25.0,
    this.bgColor = const Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
    required this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);
}
```

Refer my answer [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464458/13997210) also.

Refer Flutter Colors [`here`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use (!) operator:

```
this.bgColor = Colors.grey[200]!
```

OR

use `shade` on the Color:

```
this.bgColor = Colors.grey.shade200
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with null values. You need to define bgColor with nullable type

```
final Color? bgColor;
```

Comment: In const I have assign bgColor , so it's not problem for null and I also tried with final Color ? bgColor , the result is same. Problem is happening for Colors.grey[200] , if I use Colors.grey it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading Map, which Color can't process it.

Instead, use `Colors.grey.shade200` or `Color(0xFFEEEEEE)`